# Linux - Find results matched with regex after each slash in path

Tags: regex, linux, shell, awk, find

This is my extended regex: `^\.(git.*|svn)$` (it's variable because it's user input)

---

These are my find results:

```
    ./ivs-proj-2/.git/config
    ./ivs-proj-2/.editorconfig
    ./ivs-proj-2/mockup/mockup.png
```

---

I need to be able to match the portion of the result after each slash to my regex. If it matches, I need to discard the entire line, if it doesn't, I need to print it and skip to another result (line).

The limitation is that the script has to be posixly correct. I've been experimenting with awk but I can't seem to get it to work. Any clues?

---

The result should look like this:

```
    ./ivs-proj-2/.editorconfig
    ./ivs-proj-2/mockup/mockup.png
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk -F'/' '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {if ($i ~ /^\.(git.*|svn)$/) next}; print}' <filename>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `grep -v` to filter out results using your regex:

```
find ... | grep -vE '^.*/\.(git|svn)'

./ivs-proj-2/.editorconfig
./ivs-proj-2/mockup/mockup.png
```

Comment: This would work, however, I need to match it from the beginning of each folder or file. Hence the "^" you removed from my expression.

Comment: This seems to be working, although I think you forgot to include the `$` this time? The result seems to be the same either way, but the problem in this case is that I cannot edit the original regexp, because it can be supplied as an argument of the script.

Comment: If regex can be supplied from an external source then how will you ensure that regex is correct?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question but I THINK you want to match:

```
.../.gitfoo/...
.../.git/...
.../.svn/...
.../..../.gitfoo
.../..../.git
.../..../.svn
```

and nothing else. If so, this is the regexp you're asking for:

```
awk '/\/\.(git.*|svn)(\/|$)/' file
grep -E '/\.(git.*|svn)(/|$)' file
```

If you add some more examples to your question, including some with svn and git in mid-path, at the end, where it should NOT match, etc. that would help clarify your requirements.

Comment: As I mentioned before, the regexp is supplied as an argument to the script I'm creating and I cannot edit it. The git regexp is just an example. Thanks for trying though.

Comment: I don't see that anywhere in your question. If you mentioned it in a comment somewhere - don't expect us to read every comment you post, edit your question to contain **ALL** relevant information.